# Query tuning SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a view name "vw_AllJobsWithRecruiter".

```
ALTER VIEW dbo.vw_AllJobsWithRecruiter
AS
SELECT TOP(SELECT COUNT(iJobID_PK) FROM dbo.tbUS_Jobs)
         iJobId_PK AS JobId,
         dbo.ufn_JobStatus(iJobId_PK) AS JobStatus,
         dbo.ufn_RecruiterCompanyName(iJobId_PK) AS CompanyName,
         sOther AS OtherCompanyName
FROM dbo.tbUS_Jobs
WHERE bDraft = 0
ORDER BY dtPostedDate DESC
```

This view contains only 3278 number of rows.

If I execute the below query :

```
SELECT * FROM vw_AllJobsWithRecruiter
WHERE  OtherCompanyName LIKE '%Microsoft INC%'
```

It is taking less than a second to execute.

Now my problem is:

If I use the query below query:

```
SELECT * FROM vw_AllJobsWithRecruiter
WHERE CompanyName LIKE '%Microsoft INC%' 
      OR OtherCompanyName LIKE '%Microsoft INC%'
```

It is taking 30 seconds to execute and from the front end it is throwing timeout error.
The function is here:

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[ufn_RecruiterCompanyName] (@JobId bigint)      
RETURNS nvarchar(200)      
AS      
BEGIN      
 DECLARE @ResultVar nvarchar(200)     
 DECLARE @RecruiterId bigint     

 select @RecruiterId = iRecruiterId_FK from dbo.tbUS_Jobs     with (Nolock)   
 where iJobId_PK = @JobId;      

 Select @ResultVar = sCompanyName from dbo.tbUS_RecruiterCompanyInfo     with (Nolock)   
 where iRecruiterId_FK = dbo.ufn_GetParentRecruiterID(@RecruiterId)      

 return isnull(@ResultVar,'')      

END
```

The other function

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[ufn_GetParentRecruiterID](@RecruiterId bigint)  
returns bigint  
as  
begin   
declare @ParentRecruiterId bigint  

SELECT @ParentRecruiterId = iParentId FROM dbo.tbUS_Recruiter with (Nolock)   
WHERE iRecruiterId_PK = @RecruiterId  

IF(@ParentRecruiterId = 0)  
 SET @ParentRecruiterId = @RecruiterId  

RETURN @ParentRecruiterId  
end
```

My questions are

> 1. Why it is taking so much time to execute?
> 2. How can I reduce the execution time?

Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: what is the purpose of the clause TOP(SELECT COUNT(iJobID_PK) FROM dbo.tbUS_Jobs) ? It is strange and probably useless. If you need to have rows where iJobID_PK is not null, then a WHERE clause is more appropriate.

Comment: with out using the clause TOP(SELECT COUNT(iJobID_PK) FROM dbo.tbUS_Jobs), I cant use the order by in the view.

Comment: @Skrol29 that TOP(..) Construct is equal to `SELECT TOP 100%` and instructs SQL Server to follow the `ORDER BY`. Without a TOP it would ignore the Ordering.

Comment: Wow that use of `TOP` is absolutely horrible! If you need `ORDER BY` put it in the queries not the View definition. Your approach is not guaranteed to work either.

Comment: @ARINDAM - I didn't say that it would be responsible for your performance issue (though of course it saves an unnecessary sub query). It just [isn't guaranteed to work](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/queryoptteam/archive/2006/03/24/560396.aspx) and is conceptually entirely the wrong approach.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the purpose of views. If you absolutely need a wrapper for an SQL statement which include the sort of rows, then use a Table Function, it's available at least since SQL Server 2005. But to be clean, SQL wrappers are not welcome at the Server side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first query only calls `dbo.ufn_RecruiterCompanyName()` only for the rows returned, it filters on a stored value. For the second Query, SQL Server needs to call the ufn for all of the rows. Depending on the function, this might cause the delay.

Check this in Query Analyzer, and try to avoid the second Query ^^

After taking a look at the custom function I suggest rewriting that View using joined tables. When doing the lookups in such functions, SQL Server calls them for every Row that it touches or delivers. Using a `LEFT JOIN` allows the Server to use the Indexes and Key much faster and should deliver the Data in less than a second.

Without all of the custom functions and a Definition of all the tables, I cannot give you an Example of that new View, but it should look a bit like this:

```
SELECT
    jobs.Jobid,
    jobstatus.Jobstatus,
    recruiter.Company
FROM jobs
LEFT JOIN jobstatus ON jobs.Jobid = jobstatus.Jobid
LEFT JOIN recruiter ON jobs.Recruiterid = recruiter.Recruiterid
```

Comment: Yes you are right. dbo.ufn_RecruiterCompanyName() is taking much time.

Comment: @Arindam - can you post the code for that function?  Or, is it possible to pre-filter your results BEFORE running the function with an `INNER JOIN` or other filter?

Comment: I edited my question and I put the "ufn_RecruiterCompanyName" function.

Comment: I am sure that function can be replaced by some table joins. Then, SQL Server will give you the results faster then you can query them ; )

Comment: @JNK I added that function too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your nested function calls.

You are calling `ufn_RecruiterCompanyName` in your `WHERE` clause, albeit indirectly.

What this means is, your `WHERE` clause is non-[Sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable), and must run that function for **every row**.

That function also calls `ufn_GetParentRecruiterID`.  Since that is in your `WHERE` clause within the first function, and also non-Sargable, you are basically doing two table scans per row in your table.

Replace the function calls with `JOIN`s and you will see a huge boost in performance.

Comment: Yes that is the main problem. I am trying to do it by Join. Thanks a lot.